# Angular material textarea (stretch height)

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, textarea

How to scale height of textarea (mat-form-field) to 100% of the content?

I tried height: 100% in every element inside directive, and it does not work.

I am also trying to use code mirror here:

```
    <div [formGroup]="codeGroup">
      <mat-form-field class="full-width">
        <mat-codemirror formControlName="code"
          [options]="{ theme: 'neat', mode: 'yaml' }"
          placeholder="Code"></mat-codemirror>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

But is still have size of one row:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Code would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

We can use rows attribute in TextArea tag to increase height

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" style="width: 100%;">
      <mat-label>Reason</mat-label>
      <textarea matInput rows="5"></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score -4):

HTML And CSS

```css
.example-full-width {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div [formGroup]="codeGroup">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <textarea matInput placeholder="Code">1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy</textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <textarea matInput placeholder="Code 2"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Comment: I asked about height not width